# Indentation with XDocument

Tags: .net, linq, xaml, indentation, linq-to-xml

I am trying to do some bulk changes to a lot of XAML files and i ry to do this by aditing them using linq's XDocument.This is working fine and i am able to add new elements however i have problems with the indentation:

the document is loaded with "PreserveWhitseSpace" because i need to keep the formatting (because of SVN):

> _xamlDocument = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(newContent), LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);

then i add some elements, and when i'm done i save the file using:

> _xamlDocument.Save(stringWriter, SaveOptions.None);

the newly added elements are not nicely indented, which does not look very nice (sorry for the formatting here but you'll see the /n strings):

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>\r\n<UserControl x:Class=\"Sonova.Chinook.UserInterface.Common.SimpleProgressView\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\" xmlns:x=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml\" Content=\"{Binding}\">\r\n    <UserControl.Resources>\r\n        \r\n    <ResourceDictionary><ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries><ResourceDictionary Source=\"{ThemeDictionary AssemblyName=Cocoon.UserInterface}\" /><ResourceDictionary Source=\"/Cocoon.UserInterface;component/VisualResources/Controls/ContentControl.xaml\" /></ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries></ResourceDictionary></UserControl.Resources>\r\n    <UserControl.Style>\r\n        <StaticResource ResourceKey=\"SimpleProgressStyle\" />\r\n    </UserControl.Style>\r\n</UserControl>
```

the  above Xml shows that there are no line breaks or whitespaces for instance for the following element:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source=\"{ThemeDictionary AssemblyName=Cocoon.UserInterface}\" /><ResourceDictionary
```

I already tried to set disableformating as save option, but none seem to lead to the desired result.

Any ideas?
best regards

Comment: I found this additional information, however i am looking for a way to preserve the whitespace, and to format new elements nicely http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/178641-xmltextwriter-formatting-preservewhitespace

Answer (score 1):

There's an overload of `XDocument.Save()` that takes an `XmlWriter` argument rather than a `TextWriter`. The `XmlWriter.Settings` property allows you control things like indentation. You should use an `XmlWriter` to wrap your underlying stream (`FileStream`, `MemoryStream`, etc).

Comment: i tried it without success, could you please take a peek here: http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/178641-xmltextwriter-formatting-preservewhitespace  if you still think its possible to do so using the XMLSettings, what would i need to specify? i specified xmlSettings.Indent = true;